# How to make a function call that happens only once in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A gem/plugin that I'm using to support my test suite calls some GNU commands that cause the Windows shell to roll over and die. I can rewrite these functions with a bypass in this fashion:

```
def get_rake_output(task)
  if RUBY_PLATFORM.include? 'mingw'
    puts 'Skipped since OS is Windows. Run the test suite on a UNIX-like shell.'
    ''
  else
    `./rake --silent #{task}`
  end
end
```

Of course, this prints the message every time the function is called. How do I best make sure that it displays only once?

Comment: Using instance variable to remember whether the message has been displayed already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *method* in ruby.`</rant>`.
Use a class variable like `@@warning_said` and check for that one. Aka

```
puts "Ruby does not like Windows here" unless @@warning_said
@@warning_said = true
```

I'm not exaclty sure what scope you are operating in, but that should do it.

Comment: This stands to reason. Thanks! I was initially using global variables, but this makes more sense. Of course, the class variable needs to be initialized.

Answer (score 4):

the idomatic ruby way to handle this is to memoize it

```
@@warning_said ||= "warning"
```

Comment: what memoize means here?

Comment: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/